# Can/Should I make my web app partially static and serve it from a CDN?

Tags: static, cdn, sites, jamstack

I have developed an event web app with three parts: a CMS, an API and a user search/view section. All written in Flask using Postgres.

The CMS and API definitely need to be dynamic, but the user-facing section is basically 95% static and seems like a candidate for moving to a CDN or at least caching on my server. While I don't have millions of users (haha), so no serious need scaling and speed, I have been looking at JAMStack concepts recently and I'm intrigued. I just don't know if my app is a good fit.

As I said, most of the pages could be pre-generated and stored on a CDN, but there is a small amount of user interaction (basically users following events and event sites). My feeling is this part could be handled via the API and some simple javascript while still using static pages. But I don't know enough about static sites and CDNs to make a decision. While I am reading up on things, I am also looking for experienced developer feedback.

Thanks!